# Passing Action as anonumous method or lambda expression

Tags: anonymous-methods

I have a method with this signature,

```
void Add(Control control, Action redraw)
```

I need to call it like this

```
myClass.Add(myControl, {Some code});
```

Where {Some Code} to be replaced with anonymous function.

P.S. Action redraw doesnt take or return any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to the question using lambda expressions.

```
myClass.Add(myControl, () => { myControl.Visible = false; });
```